# Can connect to WiFi but cannot go on the Internet (Ubuntu 12.04)

Tags: 12.04, wireless, intel-wireless

I recently got myself a new HP Pavilion dm4-2102eo with a built-in Intel Centrino Wireless-N 1030 WiFi adapter. After messing a bit around with the partitions on the hard drive, I finally got to install the latest version of Ubuntu (12.04), now running a dualboot setup with the pre-installed Windows 7 (using GRUB).

So far everything has been running smoothly. Ubuntu quickly found drivers for almost all of my computer's hardware. That included drivers for the Wireless-N 1030 card -- or so I thought!

After having installed Ubuntu, I connected to my home WLAN (which was visible along with a range of other wireless networks in my neighborhood). I entered my WPA password and connected successfully. I opened up Firefox, typed in gmail.com, hit Enter and... Nothing happened! It kept on loading until it finally gave up and said that the connection could not be established.

I am now back on my Windows partition where the Internet works flawlessly. So does it on my iPhone, my mother's iPad and my brother's MBP. Since a lot of different devices are able to log onto our wireless network, the problem must lie within the Ubuntu installation.

I have taken screenshots of the connection settings ([see here](http://ge.tt/2ZYvZPN/v/0)) and of the output of running the command  `ifconfig` in Terminal ([see here](http://ge.tt/2ZYvZPN/v/1)).

I am confident with Terminal and know how to do some basic operations but I have no clue of where to start here. I have been searching for solutions online but it seems that most people have different setups and need different solutions. I hope that you guys will be able to help me out.

Thank you so much!

Best regards,
Sebastian

Comment: Who did the setup for your router? Maybe you have MAC Access control enabled? Then you need to add your new wifi device to the list of allowed internet users. (just a thought)

Answer (score 0):

When I look at your pictures I see that your device has sent packets back and forth and gotten an IP address from your DHCP server, probably on your router.

Is 192.168.1.1 your router? How does that address and the addresses for your domain name servers match up with what Windows displays?

Assuming 192.168.1.1 is your router, let me suggest some debugging steps.

Please open a terminal session with Alt-Ctrl-T and enter:

```
ping 192.168.1.1
```

you should get repeated answers from that address.

```
ping 89.150.129.10
```

and

```
ping 89.150.129.22
```

and

```
ping 8.8.8.8
```

These will tell you whether you can reach your router, your domain name servers, and a google domain name server.

If you configure your router with a web browser you can also enter:

```
firefox http://192.168.1.1
```

If you can reach everything but the 89.150.129.10 and 89.150.129.10 addresses you may have to configure your system to use a different domain name server--just a hunch.

To communicate with a website like ubuntu.com you need:

1. A valid address for your computer and a working interface to go with it. ✓
2. A valid address for your router on that network, matching your address prefix. ?
3. A valid address for a domain name server ?
4. Internet connectivity from your router to the domain name server (probably, if the domain name server addresses on Ubuntu match Windows)
5. Internet connectivity from your router to ubuntu.com. (✓, assuming you can reach ubuntu.com from Windows)

Answer (score 0):

My friend, if you use the software called `Unup router`, then please remove it. This can be the main cause of the problem.

Comment: You should tell him why, shouldn't you?